# Selinux denying writing to /var/www/tmp even though the context is httpd_sys_rw_content_t

Tags: apache, selinux

**Problem:**

`httpd` is unable to write to `/var/www/tmp` because it is being blocked by SELinux.

**Description:** A PDF report library which I'm using to download reports from my website is throwing 'Permission Denied' errors since it is unable to write to `/var/www/tmp`. I have set the `tmp` folder location of `php` to `/var/www/tmp`. The `/var/www/tmp` is owned by `apache`. Also its context has been set to `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`. Still `httpd` is unable to write in this directory.

What am I missing?

I have set the context and permissions using below commands.

`chown -R apache:apache /var/www/tmp`
`semanage fcontext -a httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/tmp(/.*)?"`

What may be going wrong? Please note, I don't wish to disable SELinux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe -t flag should be added in semanage command to specify the type. After that apply the changes using restorecon -v